# not able to display image using a variable to store image URL

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook

[image]

I have stored the image URL in cover_url variable.

When I display the image using the variable, its broken but when I paste directly the URL, it works!

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the quotes for the html to know that the src attribute is a string.
This the output when you print the variable.

```
<center><img src=https://i.scdn.io/... /></center>
```

This way, what comes after your src attribute isn't considered as a string.
The solution in your case would be just by adding the quotes symbol.

```
<center><img src="{cover_url}" /></center>
```

Hope this was helpful.